# Apache Poi Word document opening gives NullPointerException

Tags: java, apache, ms-word, apache-poi

I wrote a program that opens a Microsoft Word document for reading and writing.

This program reads the Word paragraphs and tables and replaces the placeholders. After the running, the program saves the document at the same file path as it reads.

If I use this option to opening the document I got an NullPointerException:

```
String filePath = "...";
XWPFDocument doc = new XWPFDocument(OPCPackage.open(filePath));
// Replace paragraphs.
doc.write(new FileOutputStream(filePath));
doc.close();
```

Here is the stacktrace:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.poi.POIXMLDocument.getProperties(POIXMLDocument.java:147)
    at org.apache.poi.POIXMLDocument.write(POIXMLDocument.java:225)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.util.ZipSecureFile$ThresholdInputStream.read(ZipSecureFile.java:211)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLEntityManager$RewindableInputStream.readAndBuffer(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLEntityManager.setupCurrentEntity(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLVersionDetector.determineDocVersion(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.DOMParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.DocumentBuilderImpl.parse(Unknown Source)
    at javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.poi.util.DocumentHelper.readDocument(DocumentHelper.java:140)
    at org.apache.poi.POIXMLTypeLoader.parse(POIXMLTypeLoader.java:163)
    at org.openxmlformats.schemas.officeDocument.x2006.extendedProperties.PropertiesDocument$Factory.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.poi.POIXMLProperties.<init>(POIXMLProperties.java:78)
    at org.apache.poi.POIXMLDocument.getProperties(POIXMLDocument.java:145)
```

And if I use this option:

```
String filePath = "...";
InputStream fis = new FileInputStream(filePath);
XWPFDocument doc = new XWPFDocument(OPCPackage.open(fis));
// Replace paragraphs.
doc.write(new FileOutputStream(filePath));
doc.close();
```

Works correctly.
I tried to save the document in another path, and this situation works correctly.

So I didn't understand why I got an error message when I use `open(String path)` method for opening the Word document.

What is the difference between OPCPackage.open(InputStream in) and OPCPackage.open(String path) methods? And why I've got NullPointerException?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: @Zephyr: Not all NPEs are a duplicate of that Q/A. Here the NPE is thrown from a class deep inside the `apache poi` library. So asking why this occurs here must be allowed. Else using libraries is obsolete at all since each user always must digging deep into the innards of a library to get why a NPE occurs.

Comment: @AxelRichter - I, admittedly, did not closely inspect the stack trace. I've retracted my vote to close. Thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [public static OPCPackage open(java.io.InputStream in)](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/openxml4j/opc/OPCPackage.html#open-java.io.InputStream-) states:

> Open a package. Note - uses quite a bit more memory than open(String),
>   which doesn't need to hold the whole zip file in memory, and can take
>   advantage of native methods

So what does that mean? [public static OPCPackage open(java.lang.String path)](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/openxml4j/opc/OPCPackage.html#open-java.lang.String-) as well as `public static OPCPackage open(java.io.File file)` are opening the [ZipPackage](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/openxml4j/opc/ZipPackage.html) file system directly from the `*.docx` file. That uses less memory than `public static OPCPackage open(java.io.InputStream in)` what reads the `ZIP` file system into memory first using a `InputStream`. But on other hand, the  `*.docx` file also is open now and each try to write something into that opened file must lead to errors (multiple different, not always a NPE, for me it is `java.io.EOFException: Unexpected end of ZLIB input stream` using `apache poi 4.0.1` [1]) as long as the writing action not really only writes into the opened `ZIP` file system but into the opened  `*.docx` file.

[1]: Just tested, I get exactly your NPE using `apache poi 3.17` on Windows 10. Ubuntu Linux simply crashes.

Conclusion:

Opening a `OPCPackage` (`ZipPackage`) from a `File` directly and then writing to another `File` works. Opening `OPCPackage` from a `File` directly and then writing to the same `File` does not work.

This is true for all Office Open XML file formats which are handled using  `ZipPackage` in `apache poi`.

To get the advantage of using less memory while creating the `XWPFDocument` because of using a `File` instead of an `InputStream` and nevertheless be able writing into the same file, we could using a temporary copy of the file as follows:

```
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.File;

import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.StandardCopyOption;

import org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.XWPFDocument;
import org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.OPCPackage;

public class WordReadAndReWrite {

 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

  String filePath = "WordDocument.docx";
  String tmpFilePath = "~$WordDocument.docx";

  File file = Files.copy(Paths.get(filePath), Paths.get(tmpFilePath), StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING).toFile();

  XWPFDocument doc = new XWPFDocument(OPCPackage.open(file));

  // Replace paragraphs.

  FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(filePath); 
  doc.write(out);
  out.close();
  doc.close();

  Files.deleteIfExists(Paths.get(tmpFilePath));
 }

}
```

Of course that has the disadvantage of using additional file storage, even if temporary.